# How can we merge two stash in git , without commiting any of the stash?

Tags: git, github

I have stash_one as **stash@{1}** and stash_two as **stash@{2}** . now if i do
`git stash apply stash@{1}` then on my editor i will have all the changes which was in stash_one.
But when i do `git stash apply stash@{2}` , then it says

> Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.

I dont want to merge it . I want to apply stash_two also , So that I can see both the changes of stash_one and stash_two at once.
**How can I do it?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the following for as many "stashes" as you have. **The trick is** to do `git add .` after each "pop" or "apply"

```
git stash apply stash@{1}
git add .
git stash apply stash@{2}
git reset .
```

You can reset single files from staging area with `git reset <file>` instead of resetting all files with `git reset .`

You can also use `git stash pop` for as many "stashes" as you have. In this case two stashes means two pops like:

```
git stash pop
git add .
git stash pop
git reset .
```

Comment: This solution also work using `git stash apply <stash>` instead of `git stash pop`.

Comment: thank you @joanis I've updated the answer with it

Answer (score 3):

You can consider committing each of them and then doing a squash with `git rebase` follow by a `git push`.